# Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to access my website's domain name, yet if I domain name/home it works?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

Okay... let's try to explain things clearly. I've used Python Django to create a dynamic webpage/web-app. After completing the website I have published it using DigitalOcean and have successfully attached my purchased domain name to the name server of DigitalOcean. When I access my website, ordinanceservices.com, i get an error 404; however, if I type ordinanceservices.com/home it works as it should and displays the home page. How, by editing the python files, can I have it to where ordinanceservices.com will display the home page as opposed to error 404? I feel like there's something that I am doing that is fundamentally wrong regarding my .urls structure and thus a rewrite/redirect in the nginx config should not be necessary.

Here is the specific error:

Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://ordinanceservices.com/

Using the URLconf defined in django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/

^ ^home/ [name='home']

^ ^contact/ [name='contact']

^ ^services/ [name='services']

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

I somewhat understand what is happening here though I do not know how to fix this. Next I will provide my .urls files for each folder that contains such:

/django_project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('company.urls')),
)
```

/company urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^services/', views.services, name='services'),

]
```

/company views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'company/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'company/contact.html')

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'company/services.html')
```

What I am aiming to do, without needing to redirect the main URL using the nginx config files to do so, is to edit my urls and views structure of my Python files to ensure that the normal URL, ordinanceservices.com, will actually display a page; preferably the home page of my webpage.

I have a hunch that it has to do with the fact that I do not have a views.index for the r'^admin/' to reach to. I am not certain but I have been trying to figure this out for hours. Does anyone have a clue what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined anything at the root url. Add one more line to your company urls.py so it becomes

```
//company urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^services/', views.services, name='services'),

]
```

Comment: I just did that and I am still receiving an error 404. Do I have to 'service gunicorn restart' in Putty to apply these changes or do these changes happen real-time?

Comment: YUP. going into Putty, logging into the database as root and doing 'service gunicorn restart' was what was needed after your fix. Thank you very much. Do you think that this thread is helpful? if so i will leave it up for future people who will have this problem but if not i'd rather delete it.

Comment: Well,I don't believe questions are meant to be be deleted. It will definitely help someone in the future. We all make simple mistakes that just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: Manu, will you please try to visit http://ordinanceservices.com and tell me if you get a 503 or it works? I'm sending links to friends and some are getting a 503 while others can get to the site and I have no clue what the hell is going on that the browsers are detecting any maintenence

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you have added **www.yourdomain.com** or **yourdomain.com** to ALLOWED_HOST = ['www.yourdomain.com','yourdomain.com'] in your **settings.py**

and then in your *company/urls.py* do this

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^services/$', views.services, name='services'),

]
```

and in your main *urls.py* add this code

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('company.urls')),
]
```